# Is there a way to do a negative match on a string using a positive match regex operator?

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

Specifically, is there a way to achieve the equivalent of

```
my $string = 'this is some example text';
my $match = qr/foobar/;
print 'success' if $string !~ $match;
```

By using only =~, and no negation operators?

Specifically, I need to ensure a string does NOT match a *supplied* value, and the testing function takes regex objects, and applies them positively to the value.  *The value must not occur in the searched string at all*, complicating look-ahead and look-behind assertions.

Something like the following might be a good test:

```
my $string = 'this is some example text';
my $match =~ qr/foobar/;
# $negated_match contains $match, or some transformed variation of it
my $negated_match = qr/$YOUR_REGEX_HERE/; 
die 'failure' if $string =~ $match;
print 'success' if $string =~ $negated_match;
```

I suspect there's a way to do this with look-around assertions, but haven't puzzled it out yet.  A perl specific answer is acceptable.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get your question. Sounds like you could make do with `print 'success' unless $string =~ $match`? In other words, just reverse the logic. I think you would be better off trying to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TLP, as I understand it, he's passing `$match` into some code that does `print 'success' if $string =~ $match`.  He'd like to change that `if` to `unless`, but he doesn't have control of that part of the code (it's probably in a module), only the contents of `$match`.

Comment: The problem is I have a black-box API (not really, but I don't feel like changing it and re-validating everything that uses it) that accepts regex objects, and then matches them against the string.  Being able to provide negative test cases without changing the system is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my $string = 'this is some example text';
my $match = qr/^(?!.*foobar)/s;
print 'success' if $string =~ $match;
```

Comment: The `/s` can be moved into the pattern by using `(?s:...)`

Comment: D'oh!  That's simple enough that I really should have come up with it.